# Make file option

Tags: c, compilation, makefile

How can I in my make-file use option `-std=c99` or `-std=gnu99` to compile my C code?

```
-include ../../../Common/C/Make.cfg

### target ###

TARGET_NAME   = myRec

### Objects, sources ###

# C source files

CSRCS = \
    myRec.c

LDLIBS ?= -lNBiometrics -lNMedia -lNCore

include ../../../Common/C/Make.rules
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set the `CFLAGS` [makefile variable](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Variables.html#index-CFLAGS-905).